# Как описать тип события scroll typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, события, прокрутка

Я повесил listener на ref элемент, но если я использую что то кроме any, typescript ругается. Как можно описать тип ивента?

React 16.8.6

Tpescript 3.4

```
const Component: FC<IProps> = ({ children, scrollOffset, getScrollTop, videoListScrollUpdate }) => {
    const scroller = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollOffset && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.scrollTop = scrollOffset
            return
        }
        if (getScrollTop && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.addEventListener('scroll', (e: any) => getScrollTop(e.target.scrollTop))
        }
    }, [])

}
```

Comment: Какого типа поле `current`?

Comment: тип эвента: `Event`